# How to split two stacked number using function vb6?

Tags: split, vb6

How can i split this in vb 6.0?
[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GoxP.png)

I am using,

```
Dim root2() As String
root2 = Split(root(1), " ")
MsgBox root2(0)
MsgBox root2(1)
```

But this returns nothing.

Comment: Try root2 = Split(root(1), vbCrLf)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few reasons that it doesn't return anything.  First, you are using a dynamic array, which has to be respecified using the `ReDim` command to add elements to it.  You haven't done that.  Second, you haven't assigned a value to your string variable.  Try this:

```
Dim root2(2) As String
root2(0) = "Hello World"
root2(2) = Split(root2(0), " ")
MsgBox root2(0)
MsgBox root2(1)
```

That will give you something. See if you can work out the rest from there.  You can look up `ReDim` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231(v=vs.60).aspx).

Comment: Split returns array, you don't have ReDim it. I would say (from OP image) that problem is that strings are separated by newline, not space.